# How to get other data beside count on elasticsearch aggregations?

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, group-by, aggregation

From my understanding, aggregate on elasticsearch used to get metric data (e.g max, min, avg, cnt). But,is it possible to get full row data after bucketed?

So in sql-language that would be something like

```
SELECT username, nickname, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY username ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

So I want to group data by username, and then retrieve some data, not only username, and count, but also nickname, which is from my understanding (and a lot googling) hard to do or should use parent-child, etc.

How to achieve this if possible at all?

Comment: Your SQL query is invalid. You cannot select `nickname` when grouping by `username`. It is not an aggregated field. Can you explain what you want to do with an example with sample data?

Comment: I just want to get other fields beside the field I used for aggregating, like when I group by 'date', and then sub-aggregate with max value, on 'sold', all I got was date, max sold, and no telling which item that queried / most popular

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations are meant to create buckets and come of with calculations over those buckets. But, if I understand your question than the top hits aggregation might be what you are looking for. This does enable you to create buckets and return the items with the highest score within those buckets.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html

Comment: I assume, by score, means search score? I don't want the highest score, I already have a field name `sales` with integer type, and I want to querying daily max value on `sales` fields, so the result is => `{"1 Jan 1990":{"max":100, "itemID":001}, "2 Jan 1990":{"max":101, "itemID":2}}`. Currently I can only get the max property using metric aggregations, and can't tell which item has value in `sales` field = 100 ( or equal to 101 on 2nd Jan)